# Variable from URL in PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a variable from the URL, but for some reason, I can't get it to work. This is all coming from another website's form, that's why I need to get it from the URL. This is what I have right now:

```
if (isset($_GET['PTS'])) {
    $sPTS = htmlentities($_GET['PTS']);

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
  { mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET $sPTS=1, ENTRY=5") or die (mysql_error()); }}
```

Thanks for your help...I'm still new to this and learning.

Comment: So the column name is in the `PTS` value on the querystring? i.e. `foo.php?CustomerID=abcd`... and you want to build your SQL string to have `CustomerID=1`?

Comment: Is `$sPTS` supposed to be the field/column instead of the value in your query? Are you receiving what you are expecting from `htmlentities($_GET['PTS']);`? When dealing with a URL, use `urldecode`.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Where and what?

Comment: Is the other website's form have it's method set to POST or GET?

Comment: I hope you sanitize your inputs to prevent SQL Injection.  I have the same question as @p.campbell -- I don't really understand what the purpose of your code is.  Can you explain a little more background please?  -- unless the answer below already does it for you...

Comment: 100500 wise comments saying "I hope you sanitize your inputs" and not a single one to understand how to sanitize and what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{ mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET `".$sPTS."`=1, `ENTRY`=5") or die (mysql_error()); }}
```

also you should be using mysql_real_escape string on those $_GET values

```
$sPTS = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['PTS']));
```

Comment: It may have nothing to do with GET values, but it has everything to do with not getting your database hacked.

Comment: @jordan this answer is **not** safe against SQL injection, even with using mysql_real_escape_string. -1

Comment: @Pekka isn't mysql_real_escape_string designed for that exact purpose, to make input values safe for use with a database?

Comment: @jordanmoore `mysql_real_escape_string` does not escape the backtick character. It its current form, you can *at least* assign arbitrary values to other columns by doing a SQL injection in `$_GET["submit"]`. m_r_e_s() is useful only for string values that you pass to the query. You can't sanitize field or table names with it.

Comment: @Pekka thanks for that - didn't realise! You've just saved me a tonne of work for my site (I've not started the db yet and was going to rely on that!).

Comment: @jordanmoore no problem. Dynamic field and table names are difficult - if at all possible, it's best to do without; otherwise, compare against a list of existing fields/tables to validate.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few concerns about the code that I'd like to point out, and they may or may not address the issue.

- You use htmlentities() on what will ultimately be a field name. Perhaps a tiny bit of data checking would be better.
- You're allowing a GET statement to specify a field name with NO restrictions. This is VERY dangerous
- There is no where clause on your UPDATE statement. All records in the table will be updated.
- If the submit was made via POST, it wouldn't hit here. I only mention this to you in the off chance that this is something you overlooked. Is `$_REQUEST` a better fit for your use (than `$_GET`)?

Comment: your answer is better than mine :)